# Pluralizing Noun Phrase?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Question regarding plurals:
Let's say I own a restaurant, and each day I feature two new soups.
Are these soups called soups of the day? or soup of the days?

Then, let us say my restaurant only features one soup of the day, and I need two bowls of it... do I also call "please get me two soups of the day"?  Would I then get a snarky remark from some college bound cook that we only feature one soup of the day?

Please help clarify, and note that I am most familiar with the Chicago Manual of Style

Answer (score 4):

If a noun is modified in creating a noun phrase, you pluralise the noun hence:

> Courts-martial
>
> Happy hours
>
> Passsersby
>
> Daughters-in-law

Two-head nouns have both nouns pluralised if the plural of the first is irregular, but only the second otherwise:

> Menservants
>
> City-states

Longer compounds will sometimes though begin to be considered as a single unit, leading them to be pluralised as such. Hence you can find both "jack-in-the-boxes" and "jacks-in-the-box" and both "pastramis on rye" and "pastrami on ryes" (and potentially hedging the issue with "pastrami-on-rye sandwiches".

This could conceivably apply to "soup of the day", and so one could indeed find "soup of the days". It is though generally still considered as a produced phrase understood by parsing each word, rather than as a unit. As such while I wouldn't be amazed to find "soup of the days" I'd still recommend "soups of the day".

Comment: I think one of those "jacks-in-the-box" should be "jack-in-the-boxes"...?

Comment: @Hellion thanks. My personal preference came out twice in the writing automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The first would be *soups of the day*. *soup of the days* sounds like a single soup for multiple days, although I don't think I've ever heard of such a thing (even if you had the same soup on two days, there's not much point in grouping them).

If you want two bowls of today's soup, it would be *two orders of the soup of the day* or *two bowls of the soup of the day*. If you said *two soups of the day* you would be understood, but it doesn't seem as natural.

Comment: *Two soups of the day* sounds far more natural to me. The chances of this being misunderstood in a busy restaurant I would have said were zero. The only problem would be where the restaurant served two different soups. There you would say *two pea & ham*, or *one pea & ham, one mulligatawny*.